# Schengen Visa: How do I show my payslips if I am on a notice period?

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, paperwork

Salary doesnt get credited when one is on the notice period. My notice period is of two months. I'll apply for Schengen Visa from India in November, and September is the month when I got my last salary. What do I do ?

Comment: Huh. That's not what "notice period" means in my part of the world. Are you sure your (soon to be ex-)employer is not scamming you?

Comment: By 'Notice period' do you mean you have given notice and are about to leave your job?

Comment: @Prashant Joshi Will you be in employment when you apply?

Comment: If you aren't working at the time of your intended travel, it can be a red flag. Show your last available pay slips and explain in your covering letter that you are between jobs and have therefore taken the opportunity to travel.